# simplegui indentation error: SyntaxError: bad input (' ')

Tags: python, codeskulptor

I'm doing a mini-project on Coursera and I can run most parts of my code. However there's an error in the critical part about the game's `match or not` checking.

```
# implementation of card game - Memory

import simplegui
import random

# helper function to initialize globals
def new_game():
    global turns, state, pairs, cards
    turns = 0
    state = 0
    pairs = []
    cards = range(9) * 2
    random.shuffle(cards)

# define event handlers
def mouseclick(pos):
    # add game state logic here
    global turns, state, pairs
    pointed = pos[0] // 50
    if  pointed in pairs:
        pass
    else:
        if state == 0:
            state = 1
            pairs.append(pointed)
        elif state == 1:
            state = 2
            turns += 1
            label.set_text('Turns =' + str(turns))
            pairs.append(pointed)
#                if cards[pairs[-2]] == cards[[pairs[-1]]:
#                    flag = True
#                else:
#                    flag = False
        else:
            state = 1
            if flag == False:
                del pairs[-2:]
            pairs.append(pointed)

# cards are logically 50x100 pixels in size    
def draw(canvas):
    for n in range(1, 16):
        canvas.draw_line((n * 50, 0), (n * 50, 100), 1, 'Green')

    for n in pairs:
        canvas.draw_line((n * 50 + 25, 0), (n * 50 + 25, 100), 50, 'White')

    for n in pairs:
        canvas.draw_text(str(cards[n]), (n * 50 + 15, 65), 50, 'Black')


# create frame and add a button and labels
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Memory", 800, 100)
frame.set_canvas_background('Red')
frame.add_button("Reset", new_game)
label = frame.add_label("Turns = 0")

# register event handlers
frame.set_mouseclick_handler(mouseclick)
frame.set_draw_handler(draw)

# get things rolling
new_game()
frame.start()

# Always remember to review the grading rubric
```

I commented out Line 31 to 34 and that's the part where I have a problem. The console keeps telling me `Line 31: SyntaxError: bad input ('                ')` but I think the indentation is correctly made.

Please help me figure out why it's a 'bad input', thanks a lot!

**Update:**

Thanks to Russell's help, this function works now.

```
# define event handlers
def mouseclick(pos):
    # add game state logic here
    global turns, state, pairs, flag
    pointed = pos[0] // 50
    if pointed in pairs:
        pass
    else:
        if state == 0:
            state = 1
            pairs.append(pointed)
        elif state == 1:
            state = 2
            turns += 1
            label.set_text('Turns =' + str(turns))
            pairs.append(pointed)
            if cards[pairs[-2]] == cards[pairs[-1]]:
                flag = True
            else:
                flag = False
        else:
            state = 1
            if flag == False:
                del pairs[-2:]
            pairs.append(pointed)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement is indented too far.

```
elif state == 1:
    state = 2
    turns += 1
    label.set_text('Turns =' + str(turns))
    pairs.append(pointed)
    if cards[pairs[-2]] == cards[pairs[-1]]:
        flag = True
    else:
        flag = False
else:
    state = 1
    if flag == False:
        del pairs[-2:]
    pairs.append(pointed)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your suggestion and now the problem goes down one line to Line 32: `Line 32: SyntaxError: bad input ('=')`

Comment: Thanks! Shame on me though... I have one more favor to ask and I've updated my question. If I don't make the variable `flag` global, the program would throw an error `Line 38: undefined: Error: local variable 'flag' referenced before assignment`. But the variable `flag` is totally a local one, with no reference to any code outside the function. I don't why I need to global it. Is there some logic behind this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think that might be because if the code goes into the `else` and checks `if flag == False:`, flag hasn't been initialized at this stage. You should default it to `True` or `False` when you come into the function.